# How to query nodes that have no relationships in Memgraph?

Tags: cypher, memgraphdb, opencypher

I am trying to find a simple way to query the database to find orphan nodes - the ones that have no relationships. I tried running:

```
MATCH (n:NodeA)
WHERE NOT (n)-[]->(:NodeB)
RETURN n;
```

but it is not working in Memgraph. Does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do it with Memgraph 2.5.2 is by running:

```
MATCH (n) WHERE degree(n) = 0 RETURN n;
```

That query doesn't use any aggregation, so super low memory consumption and linear algorithmic complexity.

From Memgraph 2.5.3, you'll be able to use the query you mentioned:

```
MATCH (n:NodeA)
WHERE NOT (n)-[]->(:NodeB)
RETURN n;
```

Answer (score 1):

@KateLatte's suggestion to use Memgraph's [degree](https://memgraph.com/docs/cypher-manual/functions/#scalar-functions) function is the best answer if you truly want to find *all* "orphan nodes", since it should be fast.

But I want to also correct your original `openCypher` query. Assuming that you are using Memgraph 2.5.2, your query was not actually attempting to find *all* "orphan nodes". It is just looking for `NodeA` nodes that have no outgoing relationship to a `NodeB` node.

To find *all* orphan nodes in openCypher, you should have to used this query:

```
MATCH (n)
WHERE NOT EXISTS((n)--())
RETURN n;
```

Comment: `Not yet implemented: atom expression '(n)--()'` -- Lab version 2.11.1

Comment: @GGGforce Thanks. Used `EXISTS()` to fix my answer.